# Rails Model - attr_accessor raise unknown method exception?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, rails-models

### The short version (dummy code):

So I have one ActiveRecord (rails model) class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :somevar
end
```

When I do

```
@u=User.find(1)
@u.somevar = 1
```

I get

```
undefined method `somevar=' for #<Class:0x007fa8cd0016a8>
```

I do not have a column in the database called `somevar`
I have restarted `rails server` after adding `attr_accessor` (just in case)
Still getting the bloody error.
Have googled *alot!*

Where can the error be? Any thoughts?

I appriciate all answers! Thank you!

---

### The long version (with the actual code)

I use Devise to manage my users.
Also I'm trying to add a default condition, to filter the results, on some of the models. This is based on 'company_id' which is in the User model. I tried to use the session variable in `default_scope` and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680845/owner-filtered-model-objects-on-rails-3). It basically says that it is bad practice to use session vars to default conditions, and I could use Devise and add some modifications.

This resulted in my `User model` to be

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  attr_accessor :current_company

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  belongs_to :company
end
```

And my `ApplicationController`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  around_filter :scope_current_user  

  def scope_current_user
        User.current_company = current_user.company_id
    yield
    ensure
        #avoids issues when an exception is raised, to clear the current_id
        User.current_company = nil       
  end
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead. 
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

end
```

Then it raises, from the `ApplicationController`

```
undefined method `current_company=' for #<Class:0x007fa8cd0016a8>
```

The same happens if I define the methods manually:

```
def current_company
    @current_company
end
def current_company=(new_val)
    @current_company = new_val
end
```

Comment: Are you sure that `@u=User.find(1)` returns the expected result?

Comment: I think the bigger problem is that I don't _really_ understand what happens with the modified code in the `ApplicationController`. I have updated my question and included the actual source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not correct:

```
User.current_company = current_user.company_id
```

The `attr_accessor :current_company` line adds an attribute to User *instances*, not the User *class*. You could use the `current_company` accessor as:

```
current_user.current_company = # whatever
```

The thing you are missing from [this url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680845/owner-filtered-model-objects-on-rails-3) is that it actually uses `cattr_accessible` and not `attr_accessor`. So your model should instaed be:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  cattr_accessible :current_company

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  belongs_to :company
end
```

This should work.

**UPDATE BASED ON LAST EDIT:**

Even when you define the methods manually, you fall in the same mistake: you are defining instance methods and trying to call them as class methods. You should define them as class methods, which is done by adding `self.` before the names of the methods, like so:

```
def self.current_company
    @@current_company
end
def self.current_company=(new_val)
    @@current_company = new_val
end
```

Please tell me if this doesn't work.

Comment: Do'h. Of course. Still when I use `cattr_accessible` I get `undefined method cattr_accessible` :(

Comment: So the literal you added last does work. However, the cattr_accessible raises an exception. Have any idea why? Thank you anyway!

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman try `cattr_accessor` instead. Still, you better stick with the manually defined methods as the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24005515/rails-3-caches-page-works-in-development-and-not-in-production) says it's the thread-safe one.